# R vs Python: Split R test & training set, two rows - similar to python drop

Tags: python, r, sample

I'm working on an R vs Python blog for beginners, I'm doing the R part. I would like to bring out the best in R, but it looks like Python does this particular task more elegantly.

I have a data frame. I want to split it into a test and training set. R does it in 3 lines, python does it in 2. I would like to do it in two lines similar to Python i.e.

**Python**

```
dfTrain = df.sample(frac=0.75) #Randomly sample 75% of the rows
dfTest = df.drop(dfTrain.index) #Take the other 25% of the rows
```

**R**

```
dfSample<-sample(1:nrow(df),size=0.75*nrow(df)) #this gives us 75% of the rows 
dfTrain<-df[dfSample,]              #select the rows in dfSample
dfTest<-df[-dfSample,]              #select the rows not in dfSample
```

How to match Python?

Comment: could you be more elaborate on your question

Comment: Do you want to do the R version in less lines?

Comment: If you want it shorter, ask it in code golf</sarcasm>

Comment: I'm working on an R vs Python blog for beginners, I'm doing the R part. I would like to bring out the best in R, but it looks like Python does this particular task more elegantly.

Comment: Does it matter if you can do something more elegantly in one language than another as long as you can tell as to what it does? You can't expect all languages to look beautiful when trying to solve anything.

Comment: You could try `dfTrain <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), 0.75*nrow(iris)),]; dfTest <- iris[-as.integer(row.names(dfTrain)),]`

Comment: You could do the assignment to the sampling vector in the selection operation - `iris[s <- sample(1:nrow(iris),0.75*nrow(iris)),]`

Answer (score 3):

I think R always becomes more elegant when you use `dplyr`

I think this is quite a nice way of making a test and training set, using the iris data.

```
library(dplyr)

dfTrain <- sample_frac(iris, 0.75)
dfTest  <- setdiff(iris, dfTrain)
```

Comment: I agree Mhairi, but I would prefer to do it in base R. This is the best answer so far.